# Backup issue in TFS 2010

Tags: .net, sql-server

I am getting an error in backing up on TFS 2010:

[image]

Comment: just explain your problem in detail

Comment: [ Grant Backup Plan Permissions ] MSSQL Server service account QSTGGN\TFSSERVER$,NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, QSTGGN\TFSSERVER$ does not have the required permissionsto create backups on the backup path \\DOMAIN\TFSBackups

[ Grant Backup Plan Permissions ]Account TFSSERVER\tfsadmin failed to create backups using path \\DOMAIN\TFSBackups

[ Backup Tasks Verifications ] Account TFSSERVER\tfsadmin failed to create backups using path \\DOMAIN\TFSBackups

Comment: Looks like the SQL Server servcie account doesn't have write permissions on the network share.